# addClass and removeClass to two elements when clicking this class

Tags: jquery, fancybox, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I'm using fancybox plugin in combo with 'tabify' plugin so that I can click on a link and have a tabbed lightbox. No issue there—but, I want to be able to click on a link that activates the active state on a specific tab and remove the active state from the other.

Here is the jquery:

```
$("a.timesheet-active").click(function() {
        if ($('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $('li.active').addClass('inactive').removeClass('active');
        }
        if ($('li').hasClass('inactive')) {
        $('li.inactive').removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
    }
});


<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a id="aa-pp" href="#reserve-pp"></a></li>
    <li class="inactive"><a id="aa-ts" href="#reserve-timesheets"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The goal here is when a.timesheet-active is clicked, li.active turns into li.inactive, and li.inactive turns into li.active

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.timesheet-active").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li.active, li.inactive').toggleClass('inactive active');
});
```

If it's an `<a>` element, you usually need to prevent the default action, and then it's just a matter of toggling both classes on both elements to switch between them.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L8v9/)

Comment: Working good—with one issue: when you click on a.timesheet-active for the first time the toggle happens, if the user were to close the lightbox and click the link again, it toggles again opening on the wrong tab.